# How display data array in PHP (from database) with specific column and row

Tags: php, html

I want to display the array data with the condition that each line consists of 8 columns, so for the 9th column to be the next line.

```
?php
include("config.php");
$query=mysql_query("select * from kunci order by id_kunci asc");
$total_kunci=mysql_num_rows($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) ==0)
        {
            $show_kunci="<tr><td colspan='3'>Saat ini belum ada <b>Kunci</b> yang terdaftar!! </td></tr>";
        }
        else {
    $no=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $no++;
            $label_kunci=$row['label_kunci'];
            $id_kunci=$row['id_kunci'];

            $show_kunci.="
            $id_kunci
            ";
        }   
        }

    ?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<?php
    echo "Jumlah_Kunci = ".$total_kunci."<br/>";

    $baris=$total_kunci/15;
    $sisa=$total_kunci%15;

    echo "Hasil Jumlah_Kunci : 15 = ".(int)$baris."<br/>";
    echo "Sisa dari pembagian =".$sisa."<br/>";
   if($sisa<15)
    {
        $baris=$baris+1;
    }
    else
    {
        $baris=$baris+0;
    }

    echo "Jumlah baris yang akan tercetak = ".(int)$baris."<br/>"."<br/>";

$a=1;
    for($i=1;$i<=$baris;$i++)
    {
        for($n=1;$n<=8;$n++)
        {
            //echo $a." | "; 
            echo $show_kunci[$a]." | ";
            $a++;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
</tr>
```

but with script above, display:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBeTf.jpg

should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzzeq.jpg

For record table key, look this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWTg0.jpg

**anyone, can you help me?**

Comment: set up the HTML table properly. You need <table><tr><td> why are you adding pipe in there?

Comment: I tried to use <table> <tr> <td> </ td> </ tr> </ table>, but when I show the data, in a row the amount of data in the table. not 8 columns for each row.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the HTML, you should consider changing the question's tags.